# Google Oauth2 settings: consent screen required fields and verification

Tags: google-oauth

I've created a project on google console.

I need to get access to Drive API, so I need to configure OAuth2 settings.

It's requesting me for three kinds of information:

- **Credentials**: I got it. I need the client ID and client secret in order to google identify my client.
- **Consent screen**: I don't quite figure out what's that for. Is it the screen that appears when a user grants consent to application to act as behalf of him?
- **Domain verification**: What??

When I'm creating consent screen, google is requesting me these fields (some of them are required).

[image]

I'm just creating an service for tasting Drive API. I mean, I don't have any authorized domain, homepage, policy or terms of services links. I just want to play around.

Also, google is telling me consent screen has to be verified:

[image]

Any lights please?

Comment: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#userconsent